# Which row .Find was found on

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, which is technically a nested loop

```
Dim compareRange As Range
Dim toCompare As Range
Dim rFound As Range
Dim cel As Range

Set compareRange = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A2:A" & Lastrow3)
Set toCompare = Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A2:A" & Lastrow4)
Set rFound = Nothing

For Each cel In toCompare
    Set rFound = compareRange.Find(cel)
```

How do I find which row the value was found in a separate sheet? For instance if AAAA was in row 1 on sheet3 and it was found on row 5 of sheet2 how do I retrieve the value 5 for row 5?

Comment: Just use `rFound.Row`, no?

Comment: ^^ but inside a `If Not rFound Is Nothing Then` if block (unless your data is structured such that `Find` is guaranteed to always find a match)

Comment: One more thing if my sheet one has multiple values for instance on row 1 column A it has 111 and on row 2 column A it has 111 the find will always keep finding the same one right?

Comment: Program goes through range from left to right and from top to bottom, so it will always find leftmost and upmost cell.

Comment: You can use `FindNext(rFound)` to find the next matching value of 111 on row 2.  On the `FIND` save the returned address, add the `FINDNEXT` in a loop and keep checking the address until you return to the first again.

Answer (score 1):

`FIND` returns a reference to the cell.  From that reference you gain access to all the properties of the cell, the same way you would if you manually set a reference to it.

Use `FINDNEXT` or `FINDPREVIOUS` to move to the next or previous instance of a found item.

The code below shows how to return various values from each found item:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim compareRange As Range
    Dim toCompare As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String

    Dim LastRow3 As Long
    Dim LastRow4 As Long

    LastRow3 = 189: LastRow4 = 9

    Set compareRange = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A2:A" & LastRow3)
    Set toCompare = Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A2:A" & LastRow4)

    With compareRange
        For Each cel In toCompare
            'Find the first instance of cel.
            Set rFound = .Find(cel)
            'Check that rFound contains a value otherwise an error will occur when
            'trying to return values from it.
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = rFound.Address
                Do
                    With rFound
                        Debug.Print "Row: " & .Row & " - Col: " & .Column & _
                            " - Sheet: " & .Parent.Name & " - Book: " & .Parent.Parent.Name
                    End With
                    'Find the next instance of cel.
                    Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
                Loop While FirstAddress <> rFound.Address
            End If
        Next cel
    End With

End Sub
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-find-method-excel
https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/with-statement